# Asset cache busting by parametrized url with Assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony-3.2

How can I configure asset versioning via Assetic in Symfony 3.2?

In Symfony 2 this could have been achieved by configuring packages version in `framework:templating`, but this is no longer the case in 3.

I've tried to use the following configuration:

```
framework:
  assets:
    packages:
      css:
        version: '2'
        version_format: '%%s?version=%%s'
```

While using this in the template:

```
{% stylesheets output="css/global.css" "@AppBundle/Resources/assets/scss/frontend.scss" filter="scss" filter="?uglifycss" package="css" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Unfortunately, this does not append the version parameter to the asset url, despite what Symfony's official documentation on assets [suggests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#controlling-the-url-used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this after some further research:
one needs to specify the package name when calling the asset() function, like so:

```
{% stylesheets output="css/global.css" "@AppBundle/Resources/assets/scss/frontend.scss" filter="scss" filter="?uglifycss" %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(asset_url, 'css') }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The package name "css' needs to be defined in config:

```
framework:
  assets:
  packages:
    css:
      version: '2'
      version_format: '%%s?version=%%s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used "sub packages", try without:

```
parameters:
    app_version: 1.0.0

framework:
    assets:
        version:   '%app_version%'
        version_format: '%%1$s?%%2$s'
        base_urls: ['%your_assets_urls%']
```